# Android- Open new activity on listview clicks

Tags: android, android-widget

Im trying to make it so that when i click specific items in my listview, it will take me to specific screens. Does anyone know how to do this? Im using the code below for this

Furthermore. Im trying to make a single back button appear at the bottom of the listview. So far i can only make it appear on every entry in the listview, help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Advertise extends ListActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
        String[] names = new String[] { "Linux", "Windows7", "Eclipse", "Suse",
                "Ubuntu", "Solaris", "Android", "iPhone" };
        // Use your own layout and point the adapter to the UI elements which contains the label
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.advertise,
                R.id.label, names));


    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // Get the item that was clicked
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String keyword = o.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();


        {

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to start an activity? What back button? You don't show anything about a back button.

Comment: I havent added the back button code sorry. Its in the xml. But i have created them for my normal screens. Ive been using                                                                     Button sell = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sell);
  sell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Sell.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);

Answer (score 6):

Start Activity this way.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.mysite.myapp.SOME_NEW_ACTIVITY");   
startActivity(intent);
```

You don't need back button in the `ListView`, your hardware 'Back' button will do the same.

Comment: Oh i see thanks! Sorry i been doing this all day. Missed the simplist way out of them all! Is there a way to make each listitem open a new activity depending on which one they have selected? For example if they click android, itll open a new activity called android

Comment: I can't think of some smart way to do the last one. You can always set several IF statements in your onListItemClick.