# Android. Open new Activity through ListView?

Tags: android

I have a problem with my Android Application. In my Application I have a ListView and each item in it contains some text and an image. I want each of the items to open up a different layout. These layouts will just contain some simple text. But I can't seem to find out how to get my items (in the ListView) to open different layouts. Please help!

```
package com.xxxxx;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Vector<RowData> data;
    RowData rd;

    static final String[] title = new String[] {
        "text", 
        "text", 
        "text",
        "text",
        "text",
    };

    static final String[] detail = new String[] {
        "text",
        "text",
        "text",
        "text",
        "text",
    };

    private Integer[] imgid = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,
        R.drawable.image5,
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
        Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        data = new Vector<RowData>();
        for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++){

            try {
            rd = new RowData(i,title[i],detail[i]);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            data.add(rd);
        }
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list, R.id.title, data);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {           
        RowData item = (RowData) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", item.mId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private class RowData {
    protected int mId;
    protected String mTitle;
    protected String mDetail;
    RowData(int id,String title,String detail){
        mId=id;
        mTitle = title;
        mDetail=detail;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mId+" "+mTitle+" "+mDetail;
    }
}

private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, 
        int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) { 

        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        TextView title = null;
        TextView detail = null;
        ImageView i11=null;
        RowData rowData= getItem(position);
        if(null == convertView){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        title = holder.gettitle();
        title.setText(rowData.mTitle);
        detail = holder.getdetail();
        detail.setText(rowData.mDetail);                                                     

        i11=holder.getImage();
        i11.setImageResource(imgid[rowData.mId]);
        return convertView;
    }
}

private class ViewHolder {
    private View mRow;
    private TextView title = null;
    private TextView detail = null;
    private ImageView i11=null; 

    public ViewHolder(View row) {
        mRow = row;
    }
    public TextView gettitle() {
        if(null == title){
            title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
        return title;
    }     

    public TextView getdetail() {
        if(null == detail){
            detail = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        }
        return detail;
    }
    public ImageView getImage() {
        if(null == i11){
            i11 = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.img);
        }
        return i11;
    }
}
```

Here is my New Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NewActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.poetry);

        getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you mean layouts do you mean a small dialog before continuing? or an actual new Activity view?

Comment: Might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663092/android-open-new-activity-on-listview-clicks

Comment: might want to read [DevGuide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)

Comment: @chrfugl Whenever I run into some Activity not launching through an Intent, 95% of the time it is because I forgot to add the new Activity to the Manifest.

Comment: @sdfwer I gues i want a new Activity.

Comment: @ PortableWorld Im sure you are right. but this time its not the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to listen to the click on the item, so something like following before you return the convertview

```
convertView.setOnClickListenere(new OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
      }
});
```

Comment: @ Win Myo Htet - if i use your code, wont i just open the same Activity no matter what item is clicked ?

Comment: you can put the layout information in the intent and in the receiving activity use that information to set the contentview

Comment: something like this `intent.putExtra("id", item.layoutID);` in receiving activity `int id=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");` and then `setContentView(id);`

Comment: I gues it just me who i stupid, but where do i find the "item.layoutID" ?

Comment: i thought you want to `open different layouts`. where are you going to get those different layouts?

Comment: that is also what i want, but i dont know how to. i gues all my codes just are just rubbish

Comment: you can assign the layoutID in your item depending on how you want to open that item in new activity.

Comment: you are almost there. take your time and go over the codes and the input you get.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Right now i just seem stuck. I gues its back to basics

Comment: back to basic is never wrong. the more you get the fundamental right, the more stable your code will be in the future. don't forget to come back and review what you do wrong here and let us know!